# recreating button Command=Function callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, label

I am making a custom button using the tk.Label and my own class so i can import use this in a separate module of a project i don't know how i can replicate the `command=` function of the button object, is this a implementation of the callback function or if not where should i look for information on how to acomplish this

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, "800x400")
        tk.Tk.config(self, bg="black")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.config(bg="black")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", pady=30)
        this = Nav(container, text="Button 1")
        this.bind("<Button>", lambda event: print("HELLO"))
        this.pack()
        Nav(container, text="Button 2")

class Nav(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        btn = tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs, bg="green")

    def on_enter(event, ref):
        ref.config(text="enter", bg="#990000")
    def on_leave(event, ref):
        ref.config(text="leave", bg="black")
    def left_click(event, ref):
        ref.config(text="left click")
        return True;
    def release(event, ref):
        ref.config(text="release")


app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to add a property called `command` to your custom button, which mimics the property that exists for standard buttons, or do you simply need  a callback function activated when left clicking the button?

Comment: @sciroccorics if its possible a parameter which mimics the standard button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do four things:

- have the caller pass in a `command` parameter, like you do with a `Button`,
- have your new class save this command in a variable
- implement a binding within `Nav` to call an internal function
- have that internal function call the saved command

For example, start by adding a command to `Main`, and passing that command to `Nav` just like you would do with a `Button`:

```
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        this = Nav(container, text="Button 1", command=self.do_something)
        ...

    def do_something(self):
        print("do_something was called")
```

Next, define `Nav` to accept this parameter.

Note: you're mistakingly using both inheritance and composition (inheriting from `Label` and also creating a second `Label`) which is unnecessary, so I'm going to remove the second label in the following example.

Since a `Label` doesn't support the `command` keyword arg, we need to pull that out of `kwargs` and save it to a variable before passing the remaining arguments to the `__init__` of `Label`,

```
class Nav(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.command = kwargs.pop("command", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, bg="green")
```

Your original code has a call to `bind` in `Main`, but if you're trying to mimic a widget then the bindings need to be inside the widget. With that, this new widget will work just like a button, by specifying a `command` rather than bindings.

This is how you would define the `<Enter>`, `<Leave>`, `<ButtonPress>` and `<ButtonRelease>` events. I've renamed the functions from your original code to be more consistent with each other.

```
class Nav(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.on_press)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.on_release)
```

And finally, you need to define these methods. Here's the one you're specifically asking about which implements the `command` functionality:

```
class Nav(tk.label):
    ...
    def on_release(self, event):
        if self.command is not None:
            self.command()
```

Here are the other methods, replacing `ref` with `self`, and putting the arguments in the correct order:

```
def on_enter(self, event):
    self.config(text="enter", bg="#990000")

def on_leave(self, event):
    self.config(text="leave", bg="black")

def left_click(self, event):
    self.config(text="left click")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such an informative answer, i was surprised at how easy this was to implement hope others find a link here should they require. +1 for the tips about the inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: how i can implement the `command=` named argument of my own `Button` object.

To get he same usage as `command=` and the callback like `def callback()`, you have to bind to `self.on_left_click` which calls the `callback`.

---

**Reference**:

- [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

  > Use the `bind` method of the `Label` widget to bind a callback function to an event called `"<Button-1>"`.

---

```
class Nav(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.command = kwargs.pop('command', None)

        # Defaults
        kwargs['bg'] = kwargs.get('bg', "green")
        kwargs['fg'] = kwargs.get('fg', "white")

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_left_click)
   
    def on_left_click(self, event):
        self.command()
```

> **Usage**:

```
nav_button = Nav(container, text="Button 1", command=lambda: print("HELLO"))
nav_button .pack()
```